# Django redirect if User has created object

Tags: django

in my model the USER will create the object startup_name, however, i want to carry out a check when user click the button again that of he has created the object so he will be redirected to another page.

```
     class Startup ( models.Model ) :
         author = models.OneToOneField ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
         startup_name = models.CharField ( 'Startup Name' , max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )

     class startupform(forms.ModelForm):
         class Meta:
             model = Startup
             fields = ('startup_name',)
             widgets = {
                 'startup_name': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
             }

         def clean(self):
             super ( ).clean ( )
             startup_name = self.cleaned_data.get ( 'startup_name' )
             startup_qs = Startup.objects.filter ( startup_name = startup_name )
             if startup_qs.exists ( ):
                 raise forms.ValidationError ( 'This Startup Already Exist!' )

     @login_required
     def create_startupform(request) :
         q = Startup.objects.all()
         if q.exists():
             return redirect ( 'str_detailedview' )
         else:
             form = startupform ( request.POST or None )
             if form.is_valid ( ) :
                 instance = form.save (commit = False)
                 instance.author = request.user
                 instance.save()
             return redirect ( 'str_detailedview' )
        else:
             form = startupform()
        return render ( request , 'str_name.html' , { 'form' : form } )
```

Answer (score 0):

you need check input name into `Startup` model and if its exist then you can redirect:

```
     @login_required
     def create_startupform(request) :
         if request.method == 'POST' :
             form = startupform ( request.POST )
             if form.is_valid ( ) :
                 startup_name_input = request.POST.get('startup_name')
                 if Startup.objects.filter(startup_name='startup_name_input').exists():
                      return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form' : form})
                 result = form.save ( commit = False )
                 result.author = request.user
                 result.save ( )
                 return redirect ( 'test', startup_id = result.pk)
         else :
             form = startupform ( )
         return render ( request , 'str_name.html' , { 'form' : form } )
```

Comment: mehdi, much appreciated however, i want to run the check with out loading the view, so the user create the start_name once only

Comment: anybody can help cuz am really having hard time moving on, i would really appreciate that

Comment: Can I use the .DoesNotExists or . Exists methods to validate the object availability for the logged on used then pass the value of the object to a class that will store it to be used and related to foreign key

Comment: @MohammadAlBlooshi : by this process if we have any `Startup` equal with input_name the view will `return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form' : form})` and Continue view processing will be ignored, other hand if the input_name wasn't exist the view will create a new one.

Comment: i got that but i dont want the User every time logging in to go to the view pass the startup_name to be redirected. is there a way to query the startup_name related to the user and carry out the check

Comment: you need using `Ajax`. by this way you can pass value of input by ajax and get the result without any reloading/redirecting page. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp the simple and useful tutorial.

Comment: i have amended my question to reflect what am trying to do, however, i want this query to be specific for the logged user and not all users, it is working but when i log in with a different user it pass the view where that new user didnt create the startup_name

Comment: AJAX is another option but then i have Foreign Key to assign and i dont thing AJAX can do that